# how to fix conflict between springboot_2.2.6-RELEASE and jasypt-spring-boot-starter_3.0.2

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

Scenario:
  I have an web application using springboot + springmvc, the version of springParent is 2.2.6-RELEASE, I tried to use jasypt-spring-boot-starter to encrypt dataSource username and password, version is 3.0.2. the maven clean package(war) was succesful but it failed to run in tomcat. the belows are error message and configuration screenshots:

**error message:**

```
2020-04-20 23:57:44.195  INFO 8840 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-20 23:57:44.211  INFO 8840 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-20 23:57:44.211  INFO 8840 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-04-20 23:57:44.320  INFO 8840 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-20 23:57:44.320  INFO 8840 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1561 ms
2020-04-20 23:57:44.398  WARN 8840 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginLogDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJdbcTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JdbcTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2020-04-20 23:57:44.398  INFO 8840 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-04-20 23:57:44.414  INFO 8840 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-19 17:39:48.592 ERROR 6892 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
Action:
Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

**bootstrap.yml:**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: yue-alvin-forum
  profiles:
    active: common,dev
```

**application-common.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8096
  servlet:
    context-path: /smart

spring:
  mvc:
    view.prefix: /jsp/
    view.suffix: .jsp

jasypt:
  encryptor:
    password: alvin@20200418
    algorithm: PBEWithMD5AndDES
```

**application-dev.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledb?serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=utf-8
    username: ENC(P+BapX4qZq6CpkfAZjdNug==)
    password: ENC(e8WREgEjQQs4zOL0re8Jg2JakDoi/ABmOf9a9VpVSR8=)
    dbcp2:
      max-wait-millis: 10000
      min-idle: 5
      initial-size: 5
      validation-query: SELECT 1
      connection-properties:
        characterEncoding: utf8
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>yue-alvin-forum</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.33</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: stop posting images of code, and incude the code well formatted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

try to change "url" for "jdbc-url" in application-dev.yml

Comment: I don't think it works, because in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties, we can see that there is no property named jdbc-url or jdbcurl, it only contains url property